# Best/easiest way to parse configuration parameters in Sh/Bash and php

Tags: php, linux, bash, configuration, scripting

I got in every php project (around 25!), some sh scripts that help me with routine tasks such as deployment, repo syncronizing, databases exporting/export, etc.

The sh scripts are the same for all the projects I manage, so there must be a configuration file to store diferent parameters that depend on the project:

```
# example conf, the sintaxys only needs to be able to have comments and be easy to edit.
host=www.host.com
administrator_email=guill@company.com
password=xxx
```

I just need to find a clean way in which this configuration file can be read (parsed) from a sh script, and at the same time, be able to read those same parameters from my PHP scripts. Without having to use XML.

Do you know a good solution for this?

Guillermo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to source the file as pavanlimo showed, another option is to pull in the variables using a loop:

```
while read propline ; do 
   # ignore comment lines
   echo "$propline" | grep "^#" >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
   # if not empty, set the property using declare
   [ ! -z "$propline" ] && declare $propline
done < /path/to/config/file
```

In PHP, the same basic concepts apply:

```
// it's been a long time, but this is probably close to what you need
function isDeclaration($line) {
    return $line[0] != '#' && strpos($line, "=");
}

$filename = "/path/to/config/file";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$lines = explode("\n", $contents); // assuming unix style
// since we're only interested in declarations, filter accordingly.
$decls = array_filter($lines, "isDeclaration");
// Now you can iterator over $decls exploding on "=" to see param/value
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good. but it doent reolve the posibility from reading from PHP easily I guess...

Comment: Edited to include a possible PHP solution.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer.. I will consider it but consider the above solution easier :-)

Answer (score 17):

Simply source the script conf file as another sh file!.

Example:

conf-file.sh:

```
# A comment
host=www.host.com
administrator_email=guill@company.com
password=xxx
```

Your actual script:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./conf-file.sh

echo $host $administrator_email $passwword
```

And the same conf-file can be parsed in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Thanks mate! Your solution sounds easy but, I understad that INI file comments starts by ";" and not by "#" like in SH. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really, '#' can still be used, however, a warning is thrown if you are using >= v5.3. Any lower version, no warnings are thrown. 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 3):

For a Bash INI file parser also see:

http://ajdiaz.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/bash-ini-parser/

Answer (score 1):

to parse the ini file from sh/bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash 4
shopt -s extglob
while IFS="=" read -r key value
do
  case "$key" in
   !(#*) )
     echo "key: $key, value: $value"
     array["$key"]="$value"
     ;;
  esac
done <"file"
echo php -r myscript.php ${array["host"]}
```

then from PHP, use [argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Answer (score 0):

INI! http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: yeah but, is there an easy way to read an INI from an Sh script?